# Resource temporarily unavailable at changing user in docker

Tags: linux, bash, docker, su

Every once in a while, I'm getting `su: failed to execute /bin/bash: Resource temporarily unavailable` error message when trying to run a set of bash commands in a docker container.
The problematic part of my script looks like this:

```
docker run \
    "${my_docker_opts[@]}" \
    "${my_build_host}" \
    bash -c \
"set -euo pipefail
groupadd -g $(id --group) ${user}
useradd --create-home -u $(id --user) ${user} 2> /dev/null

echo \"${user} ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL\" >> /etc/sudoers

su ${user} << EOF
    set -euo pipefail
    ${COMMAND}
EOF"
```

We do this so that we avoid having the files created as root. But one out of four times I end up getting the `su: failed to execute /bin/bash: Resource temporarily unavailable` message.

What could cause this issue?

Comment: You generally don’t use `su` or `sudo` in Docker at all.  If you have complex startup-time setup like this to do, you would usually write it into a script that gets built into your image.

Comment: > We do this so that we avoid having the files created as root.
You shouldn't be running the container as root.
Also, if you want to run the container as a specific user, you can also use the docker option `docker run -u="${UID}" ...`